Wget downloads folder structure but no files
I'm trying to download all .nc files from this website:
https://data.seaice.uni-bremen.de/MultiYearIce/ascat-amsr2/final/Antarctic/netcdf/2021/

Using:
wget -m https://data.seaice.uni-bremen.de/MultiYearIce/ascat-amsr2/final/Antarctic/netcdf/2021 -P /scratch/robbie/mels_ice_type

I've also tried with a bunch of flags, like adding: -A * -pk -e robots=off before the https argument.
Unfortunately wget downloads the folder structure and index files but not the .nc files.
What tool would be appropriate to do this, or how can I use wget to accomplish this?

I would use -i option to tell GNU wget to treat given page as list of links that is
wget -nc -i https://data.seaice.uni-bremen.de/MultiYearIce/ascat-amsr2/final/Antarctic/netcdf/2021/

I also use -nc to inform GNU wget to not download same-named file multiple times. Keep in mind that it will grab all files linked, not only nc files, but as far as I can say files of other types are few, so you could be able to remove them manually after download commences.
